# React Testing Library - Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined] - value from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-testing-library, react-testing

Am new in writing testcases using React Test library.

Here is my component

```
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    class MyContainer extends React.Component {
      static propTypes = {
        graphicalData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      };
      render() {
        const { graphicalData } = this.props;
        return (
         graphicalData && (
            <div>
             /////some action and rendering
        </div>
        ))}
        }
        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        graphicalData: state.design.contents ? state.design.contents.graphicalData : {},
      };
    };
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({});
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyContainer)));
```

So i am writing my test case file using React Testing library

```
    import React from 'react';
    import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
    import { render, cleanup, shallow } from '@testing-library/react';
    import MyContainer from '../../MyContainer';
    import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    const mockStore = configureMockStore();
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    
    
    const store = mockStore({
        state: {
            design: {
              contents: {
                graphicalModel: { cars: [{},{}], bikes: [{},{}] },
              },
            },
          },
    });
    
    afterEach(cleanup);
    
    it('renders without crashing', () => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MyContainer />
        </Provider>,
        div
      );
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
    });
```

Am not sure what went wrong , my idea is to check if the component loads without crashing , also if the cars array length is greater than 0 , check something rendered on page.

But am getting some error, any help with example or suggestion will save my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems correct. Check the structure that you have passed into the `mockStore()` function.
It is

```
state: {
  design: {
    contents: {
      graphicalModel: { cars: [{},{}], bikes: [{},{}] },
    },
  },
},
```

So, when you access in your MyContainer, you should access it as

```
state.state.design.contents
```

It is just that you have an extra hierarchy in the state object.

Or, if you don't want to change the component, change the structure of the state passed into your `mockStore()` method as:

```
const store = mockStore({
  design: {
    contents: {
      graphicalModel: { cars: [{},{}], bikes: [{},{}] },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: see am rendering my MyContainer correctly , but am having issue while running test cases . When i run npm test , am getting error like cannot read property contents of undefined

Comment: I meant the same. Inside your `mapStateToProps`, do this: `state.state.design.contents`. It's because your test method is passing an extra hierarchical key to the component.

Comment: still am not able to understand why you are saying to change in component rather than test file. would you mind to help with fiddle or running example

Comment: :) I have updated the answer with an alternate approach, where I am not changing your component. Instead, the state fed into the `mockStore()` method is changed.